# The use of BufferedInputStream

Tags: java

What does BufferedInputStream do in a program. I'm currently learning to download images from the internet using java, all of the tutorial I've been through was using this and every single one doesn't explain to me the usage of this function.

Comment: To be an effective Java developer, you need to learn to rely on the documentation—in this case, the [documentation of BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html).

Answer (score 6):

The Java `BufferedInputStream` class, `java.io.BufferedInputStream`, provides reading of chunks of bytes and buffering for a Java `InputStream`, including any subclasses of `InputStream`. Reading larger chunks of bytes and buffering them can speed up IO quite a bit.

Rather than read one byte at a time from the network or disk, the `BufferedInputStream` reads a larger block at a time into an internal buffer. When you read a byte from the Java `BufferedInputStream` you are therefore reading it from its internal buffer. When the buffer is fully read, the `BufferedInputStream` reads another larger block of data into the buffer.

This is typically much faster than reading a single byte at a time from an `InputStream`, especially for disk access and larger data amounts.